# Piping audio from multiple webpages into a multichannel stream

Tags: linux, alsa, jack

I'm looking for a solution to take the HTML5 audio from multiple tabs in a browser (I don't care which browser) and mix them into 1 multichannel audio stream.

For example a 5.1 channel stream
Browser tab 'A' --> Stream 1 - Front Left Channel
Browser tab 'B' --> Stream 1 - Front Right Channel
Browser tab 'C' --> Stream 1 - Rear Left Channel
....

In another area I intend to split the stream to listen to different channels separately, but at this point I'm just trying to create the audio stream.  I've read documentation for ALSA and JACK and am having trouble trying to find this exact scenario.

Comment: that's *exactly* what your sound system does. Pipewire, or pulseaudio, or jack: that's their job already. ALSA itself is "just" the audio hardware driver firmware. There's plugins for it that can do (parts) of this, but you universally want to use a browser together with a proper pipewire, or jack.

Comment: What you describe can actually done with what your distro ships as sound system by default: probably pulseaudio or the compatible pipewire, and the sound mixer program `pavucontrol`.

Comment: I agree, I assumed that was the case....but the question still remains as to how?

Comment: pavucontrol, as said.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively (besides jack and other virtual audio cables) you could include all those browser windows in OBS and use OBS virtual camera to feed that signal elsewhere as a "webcam"